# Программирование на языке java. Как исправить ошибку?

Tags: java

Error:(11, 32) java: 'void' type not allowed here

package com.javacourse.se.lesson4;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class met3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" Введите год ");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(teg1(a));


    }

    static void teg1(int a) {
        System.out.println("\nЗадание 7.");
        if (!(a % 4 == 0) || ((a % 100 == 0) && !(a % 400 == 0)))
            System.out.println(a + " г. не високосный");
        else System.out.println(a + " г. високосный");
    }
}
```

Comment: Привет. Было-бы не плохо если-бы ты скинул какие ошибки выводит компилятор.

Comment: boolean leapYear = LocalDate.of(a, 1, 1).isLeapYear(); ошибка исправляется примерно таким кодом

Comment: System.out.println(teg1(a));  измените на просто teg1(a);  Это void метод, он ничего не возвращает, выводить в консоль там нечего, соответственно ошибка в методе pritln()

Answer (score 0):

`teg1(a)` - Ничего не возвращает, а вы его добавили в параметры функции println.

```
System.out.println(teg1(a));
```

И ещё проблемный класс

```
error: class met3 is public, should be declared in a file namedmet3.java
public class met3 {
^^^^^^
```

Исправляеться простым переиминованием класса в Main.

Рабочий код https://onlinegdb.com/By6_vzwdI

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" Введите год ");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        teg1(a);
    }

    static void teg1(int a) {
        System.out.println("\nЗадание 7.");
        if (!(a % 4 == 0) || ((a % 100 == 0) && !(a % 400 == 0)))
            System.out.println(a + " г. не високосный");
        else System.out.println(a + " г. високосный");
    }
}
```